# AJAX not changing/redirecting from login page to dashboard [flask backend]

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, ajax

I am using the post method for the login. My ajax function sends the data successfully to my flask backend server [I know because it returns a response to my ajax]. Supposedly, after receiving the respnse from the backend, my ajax success handler will navigate/redirect to the dashboard page but IT DOES NOT! How do I make it navigate/redirect to another page/url?It returns a 200 status code so I do not know why it does not display the dashboard page.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

I have tried using window.location.href, window.location.replace but to no avail, still it does not work. I have also tried changing the method to GET but its still the same. *I have also set async to false because ajax would not post if I would not set it to false*.

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/processlogin',
    data: JSON.stringify(loginobject),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function (resp) {
        window.location.href = ("http://127.0.0.1:5000/dashboard");
    },//success
    failure: function (resp) {
        alert(resp.message);
    }

});
```

**backend flask functions**
This functions work 100%. Already tested it with POSTMAN. I have also queried the database using my stored procedure and it does well.

This displays the login form

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

This processes the ajax's sent data. In short this is the function ajax is communicating with

```
@app.route('/processlogin', methods=['POST'])
def processlogin():
    loginobject = request.get_json(force=True)
    username = loginobject['username']
    password = loginobject['password']

    try:
        dbpassword = callstoredproc("getpassword", (username,))[0][0]
        if dbpassword == 'null':
            return jsonify({'status':'error', 'message':'Username does not exist!'})
        elif bcrypt.verify(password, dbpassword) == True:
            return jsonify({'status':'ok'})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And this is what I am trying to display: the dashboard html

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

Comment: Put an alert()/console.log() call to the "success" callback and look if it's shown to be sure you are coming back correctly

Comment: @Michael I already tried that... when I entered a wrong password, it goes to the eerror handler but when I enter the correct ones, instead of navigating to the page I specified in the success handler, it alerts 'undefined' but in the console, it returns a status code of 200

Comment: Try to simplify your use case. For example replace the ajax call to your backend to a dummy rest api (like I did in the jsFiddle) and look if it's working. If this works you know that the response from your backend is somehow "broken" and invalid.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Remove the curved brackets and try again:</strike>

```
window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/dashboard";
```

It works also with curved brackets so just be sure that your response arrive correctly to the **success** callback.

See also [best answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/7617251).

It should also be **error** instead of **failure** as error callback.

```
error: function (resp) {
    alert(resp.message);
}
```

[jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/u8rem57p/25/)